# Разная работа Android Studio 2.3 в одном и том же проекте на OS X и Windows10

Tags: android-studio

Большая просьба - дочитать до конца

Android Studio 2.3 на windows10 выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. > 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException:
duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class in windows
```

Самое интересное в том, что у меня рядом MacMini стоит и когда я этот же самый проект собираю на этом маке, этой ошибки не возникает.

Начал гуглить и нашёл такую вещь:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185512/android-gradle-compiling-commons-io-creates-duplicate-in-library-tree](http://%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20en.so)

"Android Gradle compiling commons-io creates duplicate in library tree"

В общем, студия на винде ругается, что импорты библиотек в build.gradle дублируются, а студия на ОсьИкс(мак мини) не обращает на это внимания.

Оказалось compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2' был причиной проблем, но студия на маке на это не ругалась, просто собирала проект. На винде же мне пришлось исключать этот модуль из robospice и добавлять отдельно.

Собственно, вопрос: **можно ли как-то отключить в настройках эту ругань на дублирование библиотек, либо это особенности студии на винде и придётся шаманить с дублирующимися импортами?** Вот просто работал я на маке рабочем год, сейчас купил ноут на винде, перенёс проекты с мака на ноут на винде, через SourceTree, а тут шаманить ещё пол дня пришлось с дублированием.

Секция в `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':vksdk_library')

compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'

//compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-core-parent:1.4.14'
//compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
//compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14'
compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14') { exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io' }
compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-core-parent:1.4.14') { exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io' }
compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14') { exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'  }
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'//надо переписывать всё на retrofit2
//Retrofit
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
//OkHttp
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2.3.6'
provided 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick-processor:2.3.6'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.githang:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.linwoain.library:library:1.0'
compile 'io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'ru.ok:odnoklassniki-android-sdk:2.0.2'

provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

//закоммитил то, что по моему мнению дублирует импорты ниже
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
//compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
/*compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}*/
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: покажите секцию `dependencies` в вашем *build.gradle*

Comment: @Barmaley добавлено

Comment: @Barmaley, оказалось `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'` был причиной проблем, но студия на маке на это не ругалась, просто собирала проект. На винде же мне пришлось исключать этот модуль из `robospice` и добавлять отдельно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо подрихтовать *build.gradle* так:

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2' {
   exclude group: 'дерево классов с дублем'
}
```

**Update**

> Но получается, это не решит моей проблемы в итоге. Мне придётся так шаманить над каждым проектом на винде, в отличие от осьИкс

Можно попробовать динамически определять ось и ветвиться в зависимости от этого:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
def boolean isWindows=false;
task checkWin() << {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        isWindows=true;
    }
}
```

ну и далее используя переменную `isWindows` поставить условие `exclude group` указанное выше, только для Windows.

Костыли? Однозначно :)

Comment: Понял Вас. Это упростит 3 строки в 1. Но получается, это не решит моей проблемы в итоге. Мне придётся так шаманить над каждым проектом на винде, в отличие от осьИкс

Comment: Получается, что Android SDK под Mac OS и Windows имеют немного разные наборы либ - интересно конечно

Comment: я немного сомневаюсь на счёт этого, так как, когда переустанавливаю студию с удалением всех её настроек, первый запуск этого же проекта не вызывает той ошибки, а второй и дальше вызывают. Как то так

Comment: см. апдейт выше

Comment: костылии)и)), Костылииии =(.  Ни разу не ставил условия в build.gradle, я пока недостаточно крут для этого, не знаю, как это делать. С моим уровнем знаний, придётся шаманить.. Большое спасибо, что отозвались на просьбу о помощи =)

Comment: а в каком блоке build.gradle  Ваше условие нужно ставить? чтоб не ошибиться

Comment: Функцию надо писать в основном блоке `build.gradle` - сразу после `apply plugin`, а применять isWindows уже в блоке `dependencies`

Comment: всё понял, большое спасибо)

Comment: пока сниму ответ, как верный, чтоб ещё ответы дали